# Is there a way to completely clear the unread items on the Hey list?

Tags: basecamp

It sometimes becomes too cumbersome to open each unread item on the "Hey" list to turn their status into "Read". Do you know of a practical way to get rid of the unread items on "Hey" list?

Comment: @AIE This question doesn't target the basecamp application but the new basecamp3 application. I've just created and added info into the new tag. The question is meaningless for basecamp. There isn't any "Hey" list on basecamp. Basecamp and basecamp3 are being offered simultaneously right now. Basecamp hasn't been discontinued. We do use both of the services in our company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this functionality was already there or was added after I've asked my question but according to this [Basecamp3 help page](https://basecamp.com/help/3/guides/notifications/clearing) clearing all of the hey list can be done by hovering over the "UNREADS" title which will change it to "CLEAR ALL" and then clicking it to wipe all of the notifications.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure about when this feature was added to the web version because it was [added to the iOS version on May 10](https://m.signalvnoise.com/the-lastest-in-basecamp-3-for-ios-2186532d9480#.8e0sly3dj).